# AI civs are not earning Great Prophet points. I now have the only religion. Is this due to my difficulty setting?

Tags: civilization-6, civilization-6-gathering-storm

I am playing as Phillip II, my neighbors include China and Scotland. I haven't discovered the other continent yet as the world has only entered the Renaissance. In other playthroughs, in Prince difficulty, I barely make it to the Classical era and all the religions have been established. This is my first time playing as Phillip, first time playing on Warlord (which might as well be Sandbox) and first time playing Gathering Storm. Is there a setting I inadvertently hit? I didn't even open Advanced Settings so Religious victory should be in play, right?

Answer (score 1):

For me the same situation occurred when I use `Shuffle Tech and Civics` mode. Sometimes Astrology may be higher up the tech tree and may have prerequisites of techs that have situational euricas (e.g. you can only boost Wheel if you can build a mine in the city)

Answer (score 0):

One of the delights of Civ VI is that the different Leaders do matter as they have different preferences, you have likely spawned a set of opponents not disposed towards religion - eventually they will get around to it but at Warlord it may take a long time!